# Holomorphic function real on $S^1$, then constant on open unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic and $f(S^1)\subset\mathbb{R}$. It is to show that $f$ is constant on $D:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: \lvert z\rvert<1\}$.

Hint: For $z\in D$ there exists a Möbius transformation $\varphi_A\colon D\to D$ with $\varphi_A(0)=z$. Consider the composition $g=f\circ\varphi_A$ and apply the fact that if $h\colon\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic with $h(S^1)\subset\mathbb{R}$ then $h(0)\in\mathbb{R}$ because it says that $g(0)=f(z)\in\mathbb{R}$ for $z\in D$?

I have literally no idea why I should need this hint!

---

I write $f=u+iv$ and know that $u$ and $v$ are holomorphic. On $S^1=\partial D$, I have that $v=0$ and thus, by maximum principle, $v=0$ on $D$, i.e. $f$ is real not only on $S^1$ but also on $D$.

Now I think I have to use the open mapping theorem which says that $f$ must be constant on $D$.

So where do I need that strange hint? Is this just an alternative way to argue that $f(D)\subset\mathbb{R}$? Do we have $\varphi_A(S^1)\subset S^1$?

Comment: also, your proof is correct, if you substitute that $u$ and $v$ are *harmonic*, not holomorphic. A maximum and minimum principle holds for these functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is proving $f(0)\in \mathbb{R}$. This follows from Cauchy integral formula, since

$$f(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\partial D}\frac{f(z)}{z}dz=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(e^{i\vartheta})d\vartheta \in \mathbb{R}$$

Now, consider a general point $z\in D$. By composing with the suitable Mobius transformation $\varphi$, we consider the function $g(z):=f\circ\varphi$. Since $\varphi:\partial D\to \partial D$, this function still satisfies your hypotesis (i.e. is real on the boundary of $D$), and so thanks to the first step we get $\mathbb{R}\ni g(0)=f(z)$. Since $z$ was chosen general, we obtain the assertion.

Actually, two easy slight generalizations of this result are possible:

1. With the same hypotesis it follows from the identity principle that $f$ is constant on all of $\mathbb{C}$
2. The same conclusion follows if we weaken the hypotesis to $f$ holomorphic in an open set containing $\overline{D}$

The second generalization can be extended still to requiring $f$ to be holomorphic only in $D$ and continuous on $\partial D$, as can be proven by means of the Schwarz reflection principle

Comment: Then the hint, as I suspected in my post, is just an alternative way to prove that $f(z)\in\mathbb{R}$ for $z\in D$? The other way I used was to use that $f=u+iv$ with $v=0$ on $\partial D=S^1$ and thus, by maximum principle, $v=0$ on $D$.

Comment: @Rhjg, your proof is correct noted that $u,v$ are harmonic, not holomorphic, thus you need the maximum principle for harmonic functions. Note that the fact that $f$ is constant can be proved from $f(D)\in \mathbb{R}$ using directly the Cauchy-Riemann equations, without having to invoke the open mapping theorem (which, however, is a perfectly correct way to prove it)

Comment: This is a nice solution, and clearly what was intended +1, also there is a typo, I think you meant $f$ is constant on all of $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: May be interesting also to note that this is kind of false if we allow $f$ to have poles. For instance, the Mobius transformation $f(z) = (1-z)/(1+z)$ maps the unit circle to the extended real line.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question: Why do we have for the Möbius transformation that $\varphi\colon \partial D\to\partial D$?

Comment: This is not true in general, you have to find a "suitable"  Mobius transformation, i.e. an automorphism of the disk such that $\phi(z)=0;\phi(0)=z$. Every automorphism of the disc also satisfies $\phi:\partial D\to \partial D$

Comment: How can I find such an automorphism? I am a bit helpless.

Comment: the general form of an automorphism of the disk is $\phi(z)=e^{i\vartheta}\frac{z-\alpha}{1-z\overline{\alpha}}$. As you can prove, $|z|<1\leftrightarrow |\phi(z)|<1$, and thus it is an automorphism of the circle. To prove that this is the general form, you should use Schwartz lemma.

Comment: Ok, when I got you right, then any Möbius transformation that sends $M:=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: \lvert z\rvert\leq 1\}$ to itself, $\varphi\colon M\to M$, is of the form $\varphi(w)=e^{i\Phi}\frac{w-z}{1-w\bar{z}}$ with $\lvert z\rvert <1$. Moreoever, these functions map $D\to D$ and $S^1\to S^1$. Correct?  - - The only thing I do not see is why I should have $\varphi(0)=z$ and $\varphi(z)=0$.

Comment: Do I need to choose $e^{i\Phi}=-1$, i.e. is the Möbiustransformation I am searching for given by $\varphi(w)=\frac{z-w}{1-w\bar{z}}$ for $\lvert z\rvert <1$?

Comment: $\varphi(w)=\frac{w-z}{1-w\bar{z}}$